# Constructing a partition of a finite nonempty set from a partition of its cardinality

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, integer-partitions, set-partition

Let $E$ be finite nonempty set of cardinality $n$. Let $(k_i)_{i\in I}$ be a finite family of integers $>0$ such that 
$$\sum_{i\in I} k_i=n.$$
Since $|E|=n$, there exists a bijection $x:[1,n]\rightarrow E$ and we can write $E=\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$. I want to use the finite family $(k_i)_{i\in I}$ to construct a partition of $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ of $E$ such that
$$|X_i|=k_i$$ 
for each $i\in I$. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why not just put $X_1 = \{x_1,\dots,x_{k_1}\}$, $X_2 = \{x_{k_1+1},\dots,x_{k_1+k_2}\}$, etc.?

Comment: Let $X_i = \{ x(j)\mid (k_1+\cdots+k_{i-1}0\leq j\leq (k_1+\cdots+k_i)\}$ (with $X_1 = \{x(j)\mid j\leq k_1\}$).